# How to search by taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I created a taxonomy called `tags`.  I added terms to the vocabulary list.

Then I created a content type called News Item.   You can apply tags to News Items.

I created a view to list News Items.

How do I set up a search box that let's people search News Items by tags?  they should be able to search by multiple tags.  So if the search words are "tutorial learning-resource", then show all news items that have both the tags tutorial and learning-resource.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, I think that you can do this with Views, so you can **expose** a **filter** related with `Taxonomy: Term ID` related with your Vocabulary. Remember that you can use the operator 'Contains' if you want to be more laxed in the search.

Comment: actually, instead of Term ID, i found `taxonomy term`.  Then I exposed all terms as a drop down menu.

Comment: would you also happen to know if I can configure this using a dependent (ajaxed) list instead of dropdown? too many tax terms can be confusing if infused all in one drop down...

Comment: I believe remember that "conditional fields" module have this feature to exposed filters.